# Use Firebase and API keys to authenticate paid Shopify website themes

Tags: javascript, firebase, themes, shopify

I'm trying to use Firebase as an authorization method for a paid Shopify website theme. The idea is the store owner purchases and downloads the theme files, and after purchasing also creates a firebase account with an email and password. Then an API key for the theme will be emailed to them. Once they have the API key they will input their account email and API key into the settings within the theme files. To authenticate the user the theme files will have some javascript that checks if the username and password inputted correspond to a existing user in the firebase database. If the email and API key inputted does not match to any user in the database then the user will be redirected to an error message HTML file, or get an error message popup that they cannot close saying to input the correct key.

Another possibility is to use the firebase firestore unique user ID instead of generating user API keys. Maybe this way there would be no need for using the firestore database.

Either way, this logic seems ok if it was a single user. But since it is a website theme file it is possible that every users website will get thousands of customer visits per day. Thus every customer that visits the clients site will trigger an authentication check with firebase with the clients email and API. So every user account on Firebase could potentially have thousands or maybe even hundred of thousands of logins and database queries everyday (depending on how popular their website is). So this is the part Im worried about.

Anyone have similar experience using Firebase for website theme authentication? Perhaps I am going about it all wrong here. Or maybe Firebase is just the wrong tool for this job.

Appreciate any input!